# What is % in shell scripts?

Tags: shell

Since shell scripting uses one character operators that are very common they are very difficult to google, so I ask here.
I have the following line in a shell script:

```
marvel_dir=${prototxt%marvel*}marvel
```

where prototxt is the complete path and filename of a prototxt file.

My question is what does "%" do there?
How about "*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the percent sign (%) is used in the pattern ${variable%substring}, it will return content of the variable with the shortest occurrence of substring deleted from the back of the variable.

[source here](https://www.howtogeek.com/270333/what-does-the-percent-sign-in-linux-shell-strings-do/#:%7E:text=When%20the%20percent%20sign%20(%25),the%20back%20of%20the%20variable.&text=When%20the%20percent%20sign%20(%25)%20is%20used%20in%20different%20contexts,as%20a%20regular%20character%20only.)